# rows.Next() halts after some number of rows

Tags: oracle, go

Im newbie in Golang, so it may be simple for professionals but I got stuck with no idea what to do next.
I'm making some migration app that extract some data from oracle DB and after some conversion insert it to Postges one-by-one.

The result of native Query in DB console returns about 400k of rows and takes about 13 sec to end.

The data from Oracle extracts with rows.Next() with some strange behavior:
First 25 rows extracted fast enough, then about few sec paused, then new 25 rows until it pauses "forever".

Here is the function:

```
func GetHrTicketsFromOra() (*sql.Rows, error) {
    rows, err := oraDB.Query("select id,STATE_ID,REMEDY_ID,HEADER,CREATE_DATE,TEXT,SOLUTION,SOLUTION_USER_LOGIN,LAST_SOLUTION_DATE from TICKET where SOLUTION_GROUP_ID = 5549")
    if err != nil {
        println("Error while getting rows from Ora")
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Println("Finished legacy tickets export")
    return rows, err
}
```

And here I export data:

```
func ConvertRows(rows *sql.Rows, c chan util.ArchTicket, m chan int) error {
    log.Println("Conversion start")
    defer func(rows *sql.Rows) {
        err := rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ORA connection closed", err)
            return
        }
    }(rows)
    for rows.Next() {
        log.Println("Reading the ticket")
        ot := util.OraTicket{}
        at := util.ArchTicket{}
        err := rows.Scan(&ot.ID, &ot.StateId, &ot.RemedyId, &ot.Header, &ot.CreateDate, &ot.Text, &ot.Solution, &ot.SolutionUserLogin, &ot.LastSolutionDate)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error while reading row", err)
            return err
        }
        at = convertLegTOArch(ot)
        c <- at
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while reading row", err)
        return err
    }
    m <- 1
    return nil
}
```

**UPD**. I use "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2" driver

**UPD2**. Seems like the root cause of the problem is in `TEXT` and `SOLUTION` fields of the result rows. They are varchar and can be big enough. Deleting them from the direct query changes the time of execution from 13sec to 258ms. But I still have no idea what to do with that.

**UPD3**.
Minimal reproducible example

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2"
    "log"
)

var oraDB *sql.DB

var con = "oracle://login:password@ora_db:1521/database"

func InitOraDB(dataSourceName string) error {
    var err error
    oraDB, err = sql.Open("oracle", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return oraDB.Ping()
}

func GetHrTicketsFromOra() {
    var ot string
    rows, err := oraDB.Query("select TEXT from TICKET where SOLUTION_GROUP_ID = 5549")
    if err != nil {
        println("Error while getting rows from Ora")
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        log.Println("Reading the ticket")

        err := rows.Scan(&ot)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Reading failed", err)
        }
        log.Println("Read:")
    }
    log.Println("Finished legacy tickets export")

}

func main() {

    err := InitOraDB(con)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error connection Ora")
    }

    GetHrTicketsFromOra()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `c <- at` is not blocking (is something receiving on that channel?). Perhaps replace that line with a `fmt.Println(at)` and see if more than 25 lines are output.

Comment: Yea im sure. I added channel while trying to fix that case.

Comment: I commented the transfer to channel and at = convertLegTOArch(ot). Same thing.

Comment: if you're sure that it's not the channel which is blocking your thread due to to the receiver side, then we need more context to figure out the main cause. However regarding oracle to postgres migration you may want to approach things differently. There are already tons of tools to do that, some of them are based on foreign data wrapper capabilities in postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html

Comment: The main idea is not to migrate the whole schema or table. I need to migrate only specific data from some rows with conversion. I have an idea. could this be a parallel db connection with postgres that couse the ora connection to fail without any messages?

Comment: I commented the whole psg connection and got the same symptoms. Any more ideas? May be something like paging query? But I still don't understand what cause of this behavior

Comment: So you have 50 records? First 25 rows extracted fast enough, then about few sec paused, then new 25 rows until it pauses "forever" 25+25 then it goes forever right? 
have you tried to set a limit on the select ? 
The only thing I see in your code that might be blocking is go channels.

Comment: No, looks like it stops randomly. Sometimes it stops right after the first 25 batch, sometimes when it reaches 1200+. I commented the channel so i had only iteration inside rows and printing `log.Println("Reading the ticket")` but it stops aswell. P.S. The sum of all rows that im trying to export is about 400k

Comment: Please enable tracing (see the [readme](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora) for instructions) and add relevant sections of the trace file to your question. It would also be good to have a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (I'd guess that your code works if you query a smaller table, so reproducible is difficult, but being able to see exactly how you connect and removing distractions like the channels would be helpful). Also confirm you are using `github.com/sijms/go-ora@2.4.27`.

Comment: Thanks. I found a breakpoint when trying to make minimal. When I change `err := rows.Scan(&ot.ID, &ot.StateId, &ot.RemedyId, &ot.Header, &ot.CreateDate, &ot.Text, &ot.Solution, &ot.SolutionUserLogin, &ot.LastSolutionDate)` into `err:=rows.Scan(&remId)` (just one string) it works nice without freezes. But I still don't see the root of the problem. Yes I use go-ora@2.4.27. I will try to add tracing and see what it says

Comment: Seems like the root cause of the problem is in TEXT and SOLUTION fields of the result rows. They are varchar and can be big enough. Deleting them from the direct query changes the time of execution from 13sec to 258ms. But I still have no idea what to do with that. The logs are about 10mb for one iteration so I don't think it is good idea to add it here.

Comment: I'm guessing you will end up having to raise [an issue](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora/issues). But having the trace and a minimal example will be needed for that so its worth doing (you may need to scan through the trace yourself to see if you can spot any errors). Please ensure that the example compiles without anything additional (currently there is still a chance that the issue is in custom unmarshalling code in `OraTicket`/`ArchTicket` which we have not seen).

Comment: I just leave only `select TEXT from TICKET where SOLUTION_GROUP_ID = 5549` and scan it into string and still had the problem, so I think the problem is not in entities unmarshalling

Comment: Added the minimal, reproducible, example

Comment: The updated code is perfect. This definitely looks like a library issue so I'd suggest raising an issue (ideally include the DDL for `TICKET`, relevant section of the trace, and some stats e.g. avg length of TEXT, number of rows you expect the query to return etc). It would be interesting to know if the issue is caused by one specific row in the result set (perhaps a longer string than average) - maybe add a `ORDER BY` to the query and see if it always fails at the same row with that in place.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. Just changed the `_ "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2"` into `_ "github.com/sijms/go-ora"` no idea how it worked. DB Oracle version "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production"

Comment: It's a different (older) version of the library (looks like whatever is causing the issue was introduced in the newer version). Could still be beneficial to raise an issue.

Comment: Made an issue [link](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora/issues/225)